# Updating database with update sql statement

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update

I am facing problem with updating my information in database 
the exceptiobn that I receive is

> data type mismatch criteria expression

```
 int p= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to update  this patient's details", " Update Patient", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
     if(p==0){

        try{
            String  update = "update Patient set PatientID='"+txt_PID.getText()+"',PatientName='"+txt_PName.getText()+"', PatientGender='"+cmb_PGender.getSelectedItem().toString()+"', PatientAge='"+txt_PAge.getText()+"', PatientType='"+ cmb_PType.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',  Patient_Maj_Jop='"+ txt_major_Jop.getText()+"', PatientGSM='"+txt_PGsm.getText() +"',  DateOfReg='"+dch_Date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().toString() +"'  where PatientID=" + txt_PID.getText();

         ps=con.prepareStatement(update);
         ps.execute();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Patient details was updated ");
         Update_Table();

     }catch(Exception e  ){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());


     }
    }
```

Comment: what is "Patient" table structure? And what `update` string looks like?

Comment: Please specify which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...). And read up on SQL injection.

Comment: sir I am using Ms access

Comment: the strcure of my database is   http://www.gulfup.com/?YH2ORS

Comment: Based on the error - sounds like one of the type of values in the update doesn't match the table types.  Strange because all columns are  text, but based on that idea, you have a couple potential places to check.  Either one of the select fields (gender or patient type) or the date of registration (date field).  Since the other fields are text fields, they should be safer.

Comment: thanks all for comment